# Open file, make changes, save it as a new one. In one step, using the Windows command prompt

Tags: microsoft-windows, invocation

I have a file `foo.txt` with just a one line `ab`. I want to launch Vim in such a way that it will open this file, swap characters using `xp`, and then save it as `bar.txt`.

Something like this:

```
gvim foo.txt xp :wq > bar.txt
```

I'm not sure it is possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ex commands (linux version using pipes):

```
printf '%s\n' 'normal! xp' 'saveas bar.txt' 'q!' | ex foo.txt
```

`vim -e` and `vim -E` can usually be used as a substitute for `ex`.

Or use a custom script:

```
gvim -S mycmds.vim foo.txt
```

Where the file contains arbitrary Ex commands:

```
normal! xp
saveas bar.txt
quit!
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. The former solution doesn't work for some reason; Command Prompt gives me an error `'ex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. The second version doesn't really swap characters; `bar.txt` contains only `a`.

Comment: The first assumes you have ex (comes with vim, maybe not with gvim?). As for the second, I find that odd.. it could be a cursor issue? You might want `1` then `normal! 0xp` or some other sequence to position the cursor appropriately.

Comment: Interesting. With the default `_vimrc` the second approach works fine. The first one still produces the error. Tested with Vim 8.2, clean install, default `_vimrc`; Vim is also added into Path. Nevertheless, both `gvim` and `vim` says `'ex' is not recognized`.

Comment: It would be fair to accept this answer, though I still trying to make the first approach works. I like it more than the second one.

Comment: ex is required on posix systems; again, not sure about the windows install of vim. The issue with a non-default vimrc is likely some autocommand restoring a file position or some other thing. You can use `-u` and other options to force the default vimrc, none, or some other combination. @johnc.j.

Comment: If Ex is not found, you can try to substitute `ex` by `vim -e`. In GNU/Linux systems, Ex is just Vim in Ex mode. Also, there are other tools to do this job, for example, Sed.

Comment: @Quasímodo agreed; this is one of those cases where `sed` really is right (i.e., we're not trying to [edit in place with a stream editor](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2020/08/06/stop-sed-i/) —excuse the rant)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple more techniques you can use.

#### Using `-c` or `+`

You can pass ex commands into Vim by using the [`-c` command line option](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-c) or its shortened version, `+`:

```
vim foo.txt +'normal! xp' +':wq! bar.txt'
```

(Note that the `:wq!` command can take a filename argument: it's slightly more concise to use this rather than `:saveas` and `:q!` separately.)

#### Using a script with `-s`

Similar to the `-S` option [described by @D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27139/343), you can use the [`-s` option](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-s) to run a script interpreting its contents as *keystrokes*.

Create a file named e.g. `my_script` with the following contents, being sure to press <kbd>Return</kbd> at the end of the line so that the file contains *two* lines in total (the second being a blank line):

```
xp:wq! bar.txt
```

Then run this script:

```
vim foo.txt -s my_script
```

See also the [`-w` option](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-w), which you can use to record a script that can be executed with the `-s` option.